# Is EntityFramework using linqtosql underneath?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am quite new to entity frame work 4.0 and what I know from my intial analysis is entity framework is nothing but an abstraction of ado.net with its storage model, conceptual schema and the mappping between these two.But one thing I am unclear is while fetching data from database or executing any stored procedure what mechanism its following.

Is it adopting the traditional ado.net approach or is it the concept of linq2sql?

The reason I am asking this question is in our project we are not suppose to use linq for some security reason (I am not sure what this security linkage is but we have not to follow linq relegiously).

So I just wanted to know how entityframework works for performing all its db transaction and whether by any chance it is using linq to sql?

Hope I was able to convey my problem. Please look into this and respond ASAP. I am in a kind of fix :(

Regards

Subrat

Comment: I think Marc_s has this covered, but do you mean not allowed to use Linq (in which case it sucks to be you) or not allowed to use Linq2SQL?

Answer (score 1):

No - both Linq-to-SQL and Entity Framework make good use of the LINQ features in C#/VB.NET - but they're both totally separate projects.

Linq-to-SQL was created by the C# team, more or less as a "proof-of-concept" for how to use LINQ with databases.

Entity Framework on the other hand grew out of the database teams (ADO.NET team) at Microsoft and was designed from the ground up as a full-fledged, enterprise-ready system to be the "next big thing" after straight up ADO.NET

Why using LINQ (as a technology) should have any security implications is beyond me.....

Yes - with the Linq-to-SQL approach, your application needs direct access to all underlying tables - read and write. But with EF in version 4, you can do very safe styles of work:

- SELECT only from views exposed in the database
- handle all the CUD operations (`INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`) by wiring up your EF entities to stored procedures

With this, your applications don't need direct table read/write access at all - no different than when manually using SELECT from views and stored procedures for all other operations.